# What does 퉁치다 mean, or what is the dictionary saying?

Tags: meaning, slang

I am watching "The Glory" and one of the characters is trying to blackmail another:

> 입 싸물어 줄 테니까 코인으로 퉁치자

> TL: I'll Keep my mouth shut for some of your crypto

But what does 퉁치다 mean? Here is what 우리말샘 has to say:

> 퉁-치다 「002」 「동사」 **줄 것과 받을 것을 서로 없는 것으로 *치다*.**

But I do not understand this. Could someone break down the bolded for me, esp use of 치다?

Thanks

Comment: “You can _pay off_ with some of your crypto”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

줄 것과 받을 것을 서로 없는 것으로 치다 = Cancel out what one owes with what one is owed to call it even.  That is, two people owe something (comparable in value) to one another but decide to call themselves even by cancelling out the mutual obligations.

- 줄 것 = what one owes (주다 = to give).
- 받을 것 = what one is owed (받다 = to receive).
- -을 서로 없는 것으로 = as mutually (서로) nullified (없는 것으로).
- -으로 치다 = treat/consider as (a certain state).

입 다물어 줄 테니까 코인으로 퉁치자 = I'll keep quiet. Give me your crypto to make it even.

- 퉁치다 = cancel out two things and call it even.

Comment: Is there a single word or phrase translation in English for what 치다 means in this sentence?

Comment: krdict.korea.go.kr lists it as "include; consider".  ""consider" may be a good match sometimes (e.g. 이 일(은) 끝난 걸로 쳐도 돼요 = We can consider this work done), but there are other cases where it is a little weak (없었던 일로 치겠어 = I'll just rationalize to myself that it didn't happen).

Comment: Hmm, we can probably say "없었던 일로 치겠어" as "I will consider it as never happened." :)